# Hostname command does not work

Tags: linux, centos

I have a server where I am facing this strange issue that hostname command does not print anything.

```
[root@localhost ~]#/bin/hostname
[root@localhost ~]#

[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain
10.0.1.172 localhost localhost.localdomain

[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME="localhost.localdomain"
[root@(localhost) ~]#
```

Comment: Can you try removing the package called `net-tool` and re-install it. Hope that should work.

Comment: What's the value of `$HOSTNAME` in your shell?  And what's the value of `$?` immediately after running `hostname`?  I'm tempted to think that your hostname is currently set to the empty string (although I'm not quite sure how you would achieve that).

Comment: Is this a CentOS 5 system ?

Comment: Did you try re-setting your hostname using `hostname localhost` ?

Comment: I got the following output `echo $HOSTNAME [root@localhost ~]#` and `echo $? 0`. 
Its Centos 6.3.

Comment: yes i did but the same result.

Comment: `@PratapSingh:` it worked after all worthless try

Comment: next time, do a : `strace -f hostname`   to see what is happening exactly

Comment: The `hostname` command also uses the file `/etc/hostname`. What is defined here?

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple entries for localhost.localdomain in /etc/hosts - this is not a good idea.
Continuing to use localhost.localdomain as a hostname is also giving you a headache.

Please set a real hostname using hostname your.host.name, then set it in the /etc/hosts for the non-localhost IP, and in /etc/sysconfig/network.

Then try hostname, hostname -a, and hostname -f to see if all three work.